# Magento .htaccess issue - internal site links resulting in a 404 and multiple 301 redirects on homepeage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

Site has recently transferred to https, all went well but some urls were causing a redirect chain. The desired URL is the https://www version. However http:// version results in three 301 redirects, https:// has two and http://www has one.

I found what I thought to be a way to correct this by using the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which replaced this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the .htaccess file in full:

`https://pastebin.com/g9EDJrjG`

However, this made all internal urls (category pages) result in a 404 error. Everything except for the homepage. I also noticed that it didn't change the multiple redirect issue (I used an online http status checker for this)

After a bit of research I thought it might be because this line was commented out -

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```

but I've just checked and it was also commented out on all other versions of the .htaccess as well, which internal links worked on previously.

I also looked at just simply turning on the Magneto 'Auto-redirect to Base URL' to ON, cleared the Magento cache and checked again, but this also had no impact on the multiple redirects.

Is there something blindly obvious that I am missing which is affecting the redirects / 404 message? I'm only using a web based htaccess checker to verify, which isn't flagging up any issues, but it's really not that accurate.

I've searched around for answers on here, a site that shows all flags and syntax with what they mean and examples of usage, and Google so far.

Comment: To confirm, if you remove these redirects and directly request `https://www.example.com/<something>`, it works OK? That change shouldn't suddenly result in 404's. And if you are seeing the same multiple redirect issue, then that strongly suggests you are seeing a cached response (by the browser or intermediary proxy). Your "blocking" directives should also go near the start of the file (at least before the canonical redirects), not at the end. But also, you may have a conflict with the Magento backend - doesn't this try to canonicalise the URL? You have `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` instead.

Comment: I had not tried removing the redirect section first, before changing as above. I did think there could be conflicts with the backend - so under SEO settings we have 'Use Web Server Rewrites' set to Yes. Would this setting result in interference?